# Zooming a view - not from drawable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi and thank you in advance.

I am trying to create an onclick zoom animation for an image in an imageView.

I am working with this example [Here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/animation/zoom.html) from the Android Developer.

which works great..and is exactly what I am looking for. However, the image it expands into seems to come from the drawable folder.

The picture I want it to expanded was created by the user, via the camera, and stored in the application folder.

This is how I call the picture and set it to the imageView I would like to use:

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final File mypath=new File(directory,"Pic_"+fileName+".jpg");
    loadImageFromStorage(mypath.toString());

 private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
{

    try {
        File f=new File(path);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        img.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And Here is the relevant portion of the android developer example:

```
 final View thumb1View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
    thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.image1);
        }
    });

private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {
    // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it
    // immediately and proceed with this one.
    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
        mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
    }

    // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
    final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(
            R.id.expanded_image);
    expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);
```

as you can see "imageResid" comes from r.drawable.image1

I know the animation is working fine...because I can save an example to drawable and test it.

However...I dont know how to get it to work with the image that is in the ImageView.

I tried a couple of things...like changing the Android Developer example to expandImageView.setImageBitmap(b) instead of expandImageView.setImageResource()

and could get the bitmap to load...and do the animation...and it expanded the picture...but the image quality is very poor, which I assume was caused by the original compression, although I was under the impression that .png made it loss less.

Which I did like this:

```
try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
                imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am still very new to designing in android, and I believe there is probably an easy way to do what I am after. Thank you in advance.

> **EDIT - 1/21/16**

Well...since no one is answering. I thought I would add the comment...that after doing some reading. The bitmap only returns a thumbnail. So essentially im just expanding a thumbnail, no matter the quality.

Im going to have to try a different root to get the picture. I tried the example in Android developer...and it didnt work. The camera never even intialized.

What I would like is to take a picture...save it to a file, that is not the SD CARD, and not the users media gallery, but a private folder. Then be able to call that image from an activity, into an imageview. If anyone has some advise, I would appreciate it.

Comment: To be clear...what I think I need is to be able to send the picture to a file, and then retrieve it in another Activity. Then only problem I seem to be having is the poor picture quality caused by the compression to bitmap. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are refering to the this link https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom#java right?
I had the same problem as you before, i managed to solve it by.

```
   final View thumb1View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
    thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.image1);
        }
    });
```

1. Removing the `R.drawable.image1` inside the `thumb1View` onclick Listener.

   ```
   private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {
   // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it
   // immediately and proceed with this one.
   if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
       mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
   }

   // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
   final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);
   expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);
   ```
2. Removing the `int imageResId` at private void `zoomImageFromThumb`.
   And link the `expandedImageView` to my ownlink instead of `expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId)`.

   ```
   private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView) {
       // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it
       // immediately and proceed with this one.
       String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("photo");
       final String localPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageUrl;
       new File(localPath);

       if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
           mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
       }

       // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
       final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);
     expandedImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localPath));
   ```
3. Then it becomes like this, this is how i modify my code, then now i can expand the `imageview` from the external link instead of from drawable resources, you need to find your own way of how get your link and link it to the `expandedImageView`.